# Want to save credit card into paypal payflow vault

Tags: php, magento, paypal, magento2

I want to develop functionality to create custom form to save credit card into vault using paypal payflow payment in magento but do not want to place order. I have created "My Credit Card" section in customer account from where I want to save credit card into vault using custom form. Can anyone suggest any solution , kindly help.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. [so] is not a code service. You have show atleast some effort that you have done something already, otherwise nobody is willing to help you. Please also check out the [tour].

Comment: I have successfully saved credit card to vault using rest api as below. Currently magento system using gateway token (pnref) for doing payment. PNREF is missing in the response of vault api. So how can i do payment on checkout page without using gateway token.